# Certificate in Eclipse Milo

Tags: java, eclipse, authentication, milo

I'm new to Milo and i'm facing a problem:
i have to setup a connection between milo client and server (both on localhost) using X509 certificate.
To do this i've used the KeyStoreLoader classes of https://github.com/eclipse/milo/tree/master/milo-examples leaving them pretty much untouched.
Both server and client boot up without problem, but the client doesn't connect, producing:

```
13:07:34.671 [main] INFO  milo_test.client.BrowseExample - security temp dir: /tmp/security
13:07:34.671 [main] INFO  milo_test.client.KeyStoreLoader - Loading KeyStore at /tmp/security/example-client.pem
13:07:35.417 [main] ERROR milo_test.client.ClientExampleRunner - Error running client example: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, message=An error occurred verifying security.
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, message=An error occurred verifying security.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
        at milo_test.client.BrowseExample.run(BrowseExample.java:35)
        at milo_test.client.ClientExampleRunner.run(ClientExampleRunner.java:121)
        at milo_test.client.BrowseExample.main(BrowseExample.java:27)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, description=An error occurred verifying security.
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.UaStackClient.lambda$deliverResponse$5(UaStackClient.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.util.ExecutionQueue$Task.run(ExecutionQueue.java:119)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    13:07:35.420 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR milo_test.client.ClientExampleRunner - Error running example: UaServiceFaultException: status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, message=An error occurred verifying security.
```

Inside the ClientExample interface i've this getIdentityProvider() method:

```
default IdentityProvider getIdentityProvider() {
        //return new AnonymousProvider();
        //return new UsernameProvider("user", "pass");

        File securityTempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "security");
        if (securityTempDir.exists() || securityTempDir.mkdirs()) {
            try {
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("security temp dir: {}", securityTempDir.getAbsolutePath());
                KeyStoreLoader loader = new KeyStoreLoader().load(securityTempDir.toPath());
                return new X509IdentityProvider(loader.getClientCertificate(), loader.getClientKeyPair().getPrivate());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and if i use the AnonymusProvider() or the UsernameProvider() everything goes fine.

Now, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458799/15197213) thread i've searched for the securityTempDir, finding both the server and the client certificate and the right structure (/pki -> issuers, rejected and trusted) but the rejected folder is always empty, making impossible to move the certificate into trusted.

What do i possibly do wrong?
Thanks to everyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the application instance certificates and the separate X509 certificates that are used for authentication. The security and PKI dirs are necessary for getting a secure connection working but have nothing to do with X509-based user identity authentication.

That said, I think this may be a bug in the server SDK, and if you want to open an issue in the GitHub repo we can look into it there.

Comment: Hi!, thanks for the reply.
I've seen what you mean with application instance certificates and auth certificates, but still can't understand how to implement user authentication using X509 certs. Have you a working example to show?

Comment: I think your modified example will work if you use this branch which fixes the bug I mentioned: https://github.com/eclipse/milo/pull/771